# SpEL expression contains JSON field names different to member variable names

Tags: json, spring, kotlin, jackson, spring-el

I have something like this:

```
data class Person(
        @JsonProperty("first_name")
        var firstName: String,
        @JsonProperty("last_name")
        var lastName: String,
        @JsonProperty("age")
        var age: Int
)

@GetMapping("/test")
fun testSpEL(): ResponseEntity<Boolean> {

    val person = Person("Tom", "Black", 26)

    val parser = SpelExpressionParser()
    val expression = parser.parseExpression("age > 18 && first_name == 'Tom'")
    val result = expression.getValue(person, Boolean::class.java)

    println("##################### $result")

    return ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

The main focus is on the JSON property names and the member variable names, they are different. And my SpEL expression should work at least with the JSON field names.
However, it only works with the member variable names (using `firstName` but should also work with `first_name`).
For `first_name` an exception is thrown telling that `first_name` was not found in type `Person`.

I tried to create StandardEvaluationContext() and add there a JsonPropertyAccessor() in the hope that this would do the trick.
But while debugging I noticed that it was in the end removed because it only accepts `String`, `JsonNode` and `JsonWrapper` as type. My `Person` is clearly not one of those.

Is there some way to accomplish my desired behavior?
It should be able to use that on nested objects and using the `@JsonProperty` annotation to get the correct name of the property.
In the end the expression will be provided as a String through a query parameter in the request. So it should also be user friendly regarding the expression.

Answer (score 0):

> And my SpEL expression should work at least with the JSON field names

It is not clear why you would expect that; SpEL knows nothing about the JSON annotations, it uses a simple property accessor to access the fields.

You would need to create a custom property accessor that parses the annotations on the fields and does the mapping.

Comment: I expect that (not by default of course) because the JSON field names are more often than not different to the member variable names. So I assumed that there is already some accessor provided for that use case. Unfortunately the JsonPropertyAccessor does not work as mentioned in my initial question.